Difference between copy increments and copy reference imputation
I'm reading up on reference-based imputation (Carpenter et al. 2013, but the explanation is a little bit too mathematical for me)  and I'm not quite sure if I understand the difference between copy increments reference (allowing a dropout to continue from its established position, but the subsequent changes in mean profile follow that from the specified reference group)  and copy reference (values of the outcome before and dropout are both equal to the control (reference)). Does that mean I need to replace the observed values from the participants before dropouts in case of copy reference imputation? Can someone explain the difference in the context of RCT?
Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5796638/
